# Average a column returned from a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

Is is not possible to average the results from a subquery?

Here's the query I'm fighting with:

```
SELECT AVG(
    SELECT SUM(`retail_subtotal`)
      FROM `order`
     WHERE `status` IN('O')
  GROUP BY `lead_id`
);
```

Comment: Before I get heck for the name of the table, it was our previous developer who named this.. I'm well aware `order` possibly the worst possible name for a table!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, an easier way to phrase the query is without a subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(`retail_subtotal`)/count(distinct lead_id) as avg
FROM `order`
WHERE `status` IN ('O')
```

(This assumes lead_id is never NULL.)

Your original query had a problem not only because of the subquery in the avg(), but also because the subquery returned multiple rows.

Comment: NICE! I'll try this and the others and award the answer to shortest query time

Answer (score 13):

You need to create a subquery if you want to do this.  By creating the subquery you then give the `SUM()` column a name and then `AVG()` that new field.

```
SELECT AVG(x.SubTotal)
FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(`retail_subtotal`) SubTotal
      FROM `order`
     WHERE `status` IN('O')
  GROUP BY `lead_id`
) x;
```

Comment: Damn, as easy as doing the subquery in the `FROM` *faceplam*

Comment: Although your solution worked it wasn't as fast as Gordons, yours came in a 0.093 in workbench

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just give the result column a name and select from it:

```
SELECT AVG(theSum)
FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(`retail_subtotal`) AS theSum
    FROM `order`
    WHERE `status` IN('O')
    GROUP BY `lead_id`
) T
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing a select without specifying a table.

Try this

```
SELECT AVG(sum) from 
    (SELECT SUM(`retail_subtotal`) as 'Sum'
      FROM `order`
     WHERE `status` IN('O')
  GROUP BY `lead_id`
) T1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work...

```
SELECT AVG(retail_sub) FROM
(
   SELECT SUM('retail_subtotal') As retail_sub
    From 'order'
    WHERE `status` IN('O')
    GROUP BY `lead_id`
) As Z
```